# The route is truncated on my Symfony application getting a 404 error

Tags: symfony, routes, http-status-code-404

I have two differents pages getting the same error in my symfony3.4 application.

It is a detail page of an entity, it is working most of the time but sometimes and I don't know what is triggering the error, I get a 404 error and I can see my route truncated in the error.

The route is : `{base_url}/app_dev.php/stock/model/{id}/detail`

On some of my resources, the error message is :

[image]

It seems to happend on specific entities but I have no clues about what could possibly trigger that kinds of error.

**Any idea of what I could investigate to debug ?**

-- EDIT --

It seems that the route is working fine using `{base_url}/web/app_dev.php` , the problem appears when the route has no `/web` in dev mode (`{base_url}/app_dev.php`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Symfony3 throught a 404 error in dev mode without the /web . It is a server configuration matter. Check https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html for more informations